# fine-uploader can't read iframe response with IE7

Tags: php, javascript, fine-uploader

I'm using the jquery.fineuploader-3.7.0 and Code igniter framework for the server side.

My js code :

```
$('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
request                 : { endpoint: 'declaration/uploadfile'},
autoUpload              : false,
template                : '<div class="qq-uploader span12">' +
                          '  <pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></pre>' +
                          '  <div class="qq-upload-button " style="width: auto;">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                          '  <ul id="qq-upload-list" class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top:10px; text-align:center;"><li></li></ul>' +
                          '  <ul class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></ul>' +
                          '</div>',
fileTemplate            : '<li>' +
                          '  <div class="qq-progress-bar"></div>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-upload-finished"></span>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
                          '  <a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#">{cancelButtonText}</a>' +
                          '  <a class="qq-upload-retry" href="#">{retryButtonText}</a>' +
                          '  <a class="qq-upload-delete" href="#">{deleteButtonText}</a>' +
                          '  <span class="qq-upload-status-text">{statusText}</span>' +
                          '</li>',
failedUploadTextDisplay : {
                            mode             : 'custom',
                            maxChars         : 1500,
                            responseProperty : 'error',
                            enableTooltip    : true
                          },
text                    : {
                            uploadButton : '<color=#2E6E9E><b>Selectionnez le fichier à déposer</b></color>',
                            failUpload   : 'Le chargement a échoué'
                          }  });
 $('#triggerUpload').click(function() {
$('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader('setParams', {'id_fait':$('#id_fait').attr('value') });
$('#manual-fine-uploader').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles'); });
```

My server side response are :

```
>HTTP/1.0 200 OK
>Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 08:12:09 GMT
>Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
>X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
>Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>Pragma: no-cache
>Connection: close
>Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

content :

```
{"success":true,"file_inner":"<a href='pj\/'116810_116810_cimpa_insertion.xls'  target='_blank'>116810_cimpa_insertion.xls<\/a>"}
```

Under FF, Chrome i have a sucess message on my web page (the green)
but under IE7 or IE8 i have a message who said in my debug bar console:

[FineUploader 3.7.0] Error when attempting to parse iframe upload response ([object Error])
[FineUploader 3.7.0] 'error' is not a valid property on the server response.

and web page error message(the red ).
But the upload are ok (the file are correctly on my server)

I'm a beginner under fine-uploader, could you help me to find where i have make an error  please ?

code of the server side:

```
/**
* uploadfile
* @access public
* @return string
*/
  public function uploadfile() {
    $post['id_fait'] = $this->input->post('id_fait');
    if ( empty($post['id_fait']) ) {
      $return['error'] = 'ID_FAIT manquant';
      return true;
    }
    else {
      $_FILES['qqfile']['name'] = $post['id_fait']."_".$_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
      $config['upload_path']   = DOCUMENT_PATH;
      $config['max_size']      = UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE;
      $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
      $config['allowed_types'] = ALLOWED_EXT;
      $config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('qqfile')) { $return['error'] = $this->upload->error_msg[0]; }
      else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $post['fichier'] = $data['file_name'];
        $insert = $this->db->insert('senla_faits_piece_jointe',$post);
        $return['success'] = $insert;
        $return['file_inner'] = "<a href='pj/'".$post['id_fait']."_".$data['file_name']."'  target='_blank'>".$data['file_name']."</a>";
      }
    }
    echo json_encode( $return, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
  }
```

UPDATE :
After i make the change my server response :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2013 20:21:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 124
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

and the content :

```
{"success":true,"file_inner":"<a href=\"pj\/116842_116842_brochure 12.pdf\"  target=\"_blank\">116842_brochure 12.pdf<\/a>"}
```

I have always a red web message who said : upload fail (in french) and this message in my debug bar console :

```
[FineUploader 3.7.0] Error when attempting to parse iframe upload response ([object Error])

 [FineUploader 3.7.0] 'error' is not a valid property on the server response.
```

Thank a lot for your help

Stéphane

Update 2 after change the content type, always the same problem :
The server response :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 27 Jul 2013 20:14:38 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7riosh2q9edldanjp9vtg4ili3; path=/
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=7riosh2q9edldanjp9vtg4ili3; path=/
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

The content :

```
{"success":true,"file_inner":"<a href=\"pj\/116841_116841_capture_portail_sonacotra.doc\"  target=\"_blank\">116841_capture_portail_sonacotra.doc<\/a>"}
```

I think it's not a problem of content, perhaps it's a problem of IE who can't read the response send by the server across the iframe, but i don't know sufficiently the javascript to find the solution

UPDATE 29/07/2013 :
I have make a test :
If i delete my  $return['file_inner']
And i keep only the sucess or error message then that's ok

My $return['file_inner']  are just here because user could be verify the document upload by clicking on the link. But it's not a very important fonction, i could delete it.
Perhaps i have forget something when they are severals attributes in my object "response". or perhaps fine uploader code wait only one attribut.

Comment: Excellent question.  Thanks for taking the time to provide all of this information and explain your problem so clearly.  It's refreshing to see a well-formed question, and I wish more people on Stackoverflow would post questions as detailed and complete as yours.

Comment: Make sure you are using UTF-8 on both client and server.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

After having a closer look, there are a few odd properties of your JSON response.

I have very little professional experience with PHP, but I can say that your response content is not correct.  You should probably be using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to format your response content.  Fine Uploader has [an example PHP script](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/php/php.php) that already does this.  Perhaps you should have a look.

Either way, your response content should look like this:

```
{"success":"true","file_inner":"<a href=\"pj/116841_116841_capture_portail_sonacotra.doc\"  target=\"_blank\">116841_capture_portail_sonacotra.doc</a>"}
```

Comment: I have make this change but they are the same problem.

Comment: Please copy the exact contents of the response, after making this change.

Comment: Your response's Content-Type should probably be "text/plain" and NOT "text/html".  Please try that.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The solution are in the example php script, my error are to make a url in my object without the htmlspecialchars conversion. With this php code on the server side it's OK

```
/**
* uploadfile
* @access public
* @return string
*/
  public function uploadfile() {
    $post['id_fait'] = $this->input->post('id_fait');
    if ( empty($post['id_fait']) ) {
      $return['error'] = 'ID_FAIT manquant';
      return true;
    }
    else {
      $_FILES['qqfile']['name'] = $post['id_fait']."_".$_FILES['qqfile']['name'];
      $config['upload_path']   = DOCUMENT_PATH;
      $config['max_size']      = UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE;
      $config['overwrite']     = FALSE;
      $config['allowed_types'] = ALLOWED_EXT;
      $config['remove_spaces'] = FALSE;
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      if ( !$this->upload->do_upload('qqfile')) { $return['error'] = $this->upload->error_msg[0]; }
      else {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $post['fichier'] = $data['file_name'];
        $insert = $this->db->insert('senla_faits_piece_jointe',$post);
        $return['success'] = $insert;
        $return['file_inner'] = "<a href=\"pj/".$post['id_fait']."_".$data['file_name']."\"  target=\"_blank\">".$data['file_name']."</a>";

     }
    }
// log_askel($this->upload);
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($return), ENT_NOQUOTES);
  }
```